# Firebase CLI commands do not work with VS Code Git Bash Terminal

Tags: firebase, powershell, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, git-bash

I have npm installed and reinstalled firebase-tools (globally), but when working in VS Code terminal through GitBash I am getting this error on any firebase command:

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

I do not get this error when using Command Line or PowerShell through VS Code or standalone, only with Git Bash. This error does not happen when I add `.cmd` to `firebase`.

```
firebase --version = error  
firebase.cmd --version = 8.4.2
```

If anyone can shed some light as to why this is happening I'd appreciate it. I don't mind using PowerShell but I would like to know the "why" behind this error.

Versions:
VS Code 1.46.0
Firebase 8.4.2
npm 6.14.4
git 2.27.0

The operating system is Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
npm uninstall firebase-tools
npm cache clean --force
```

If that doesn't work then you should physically delete `C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npm` and `C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache` and reinstall global npm modules.

There is an open issue regarding this [error](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/29287), which is similar to your error.